# Why does 'kubectl' sometimes return a *node* name instead of the *pod* name if the specified pod no longer exists in the cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Sometimes `kubectl get pod some-pod-1234abc` returns an error like: `Error from server (NotFound): pods "ip-192-168-55-196.us-east-1.compute.internal" not found`. This is surprising because the error references a **node**, not a **pod** name. This happens very rarely, and *seems to be* (I've yet to verify this with certainty) happening only for pods that were **recently** deleted.

What conditions could cause this to happen? this is a Kubernetes 1.20 cluster in AWS EKS, using Spot instances. I am not concerned with the pods being deleted, but am trying to understand why the **node** name is returned by `kubectl` in the message, instead of the **pod** name.

Comment: You can try dialing up the verbosity of kubectl to see what, exactly, it is requesting. Usually the mention of Node names when trying to interact with Pod resources is for the logs, since it needs to contact kubelet on port 10254 to obtain the logs, but I don't recall ever having seen that behavior with just a `get pods` operation

Comment: Hello @ebr. Any updates?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor check Rajesh Dutta's answer below. It makes sense that the pod gets a DNS entry that *looks* like a node name, but in fact is simply a standard internal DNS name used by AWS networking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. That is how a Pod is registered in DNS(AAAA record).

Syntax: **pod-ip-address**.**namespace**.pod.**cluster**

In my understanding:

Pod

- ip-address = ip-192-168-55-196
- namespace = us-east-1
- Cluster = compute.internal

Check this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-aaaa-records-1).